# How can I get the page number for a specific field in iText?

Tags: java, itext, acrofields

How can I get from which page is the field coming from?

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(path);
AcroFields fields = reader.getAcroFields();
Set<String> fieldNames = fields.getFields.keySet();
for(String fieldName : fieldNames)
{
     String fieldValue = fields.getField(fieldName);
    //get page number for this field
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the `getFieldPositions()` method. One field can correspond with more than one widget annotation. For instance, a field with name `fieldName` can be visualized on different pages, hence the method returns a `List`.

So if you want to get the page of the first (or only) item, you need:

```
int page = form.getFieldPositions(name).get(0).page;
```

By the way: the coordinates can be found like this:

```
Rectangle rectangle = form.getFieldPositions(name).get(0).position;
```

Comment: Thank you! That helped me :).